# Preserving the headings when exporting a table

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I have the following `SparseArray`:

```
s = SparseArray[
   {{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 2, {1, 3} -> 3,
    {2, 1} -> 4, {2, 2} -> 5, {2, 3} -> 6,
    {3, 1} -> 7, {3, 2} -> 8, {3, 3} -> 9}];
```

I label it as follow:

```
TableForm[s, TableHeadings -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"E", "F", "G"}}]
```

I can then export this to csv as,

```
Export["Desktop/test.csv", 
 TableForm[s, TableHeadings -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"A", "B", "C"}}]]
```

yet doing this does not preserve the heading labels. I wonder how can I keep them in the csv file?

Comment: Use `TableHeadings -> ...` as option to `Export`.

Comment: @Alx thanks, can you please expand? I am not sure how to used this as option, my last command had the tableheadings so I'm not sure how else to keep it as option.

Comment: This works for me: `Export["test.csv", s, "TableHeadings" -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"E", "F", "G"}}]`, help page on CSV has similar example of using "TableHeadings".

Comment: @Alx, I think your comment is worthy of an answer! It's true that the `"TableHeadings"` option for `Export` is in the docs, but I for one was not aware of it. and had not even thought of looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @MarcoB in comments, I post my comment as answer.

In the documentation on CSV format one can find that `Export` command to this format has an option `"TableHeadings"`, so we can use this to keep headings in exported file:

```
Export["test.csv", s, "TableHeadings" -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"E", "F", "G"}}]
```

> `"","E","F","G"
>   "A",1,2,3
>   "B",4,5,6
>   "C",7,8,9`

Comment: Thank you for posting it! (+1)